# Flow error Cannot get `x` because property `y` is missing in `Array` [1]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a type guard for state as follow -

```
/** Type guard for states */
type demo= {
  demoList: {[key: number]: Array<{
        name?: string,
        length?: string,
    }>
  },
  status: boolean
}
```

I am initializing the state as follow inside my class.

```
  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      demoList: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-computed-key
        [0]: {
          name: '',
          length: '',
        }
      },
      status: false
    };
  }
```

And when the user will enter something in the name and length field I update the state as follow inside my onChange method

```
this.setState({
  demoList:
  { ...this.state.demoList, [index]: { name: inputName, length: inputLength} }
});
```

The error I am getting is when I try to render the value inside render(). I am trying to replace the value in the name or length field by fetching like below

```
this.state.demoList[index].name
```

But the error I am getting is

```
Cannot get `this.state.demoList[index].name` because property `name` is missing in  `Array` [1].Flow(InferError)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have issue with the `Type Guard`. You are not using the `type guard` as per the definition given in its `type`.

I have created a code-sandbox based on your problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-waterfall-c6uu0?file=/src/Demo.tsx

Though for further clarification, you are using your `Type Guard` `type` as below:

```
constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      demoList: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-computed-key
        [0]: {
          name: '',
          length: '',
        }
      },
      status: false
    };
  }
```

But, as per the `type` definition of your `Type Guard` it should be used as:

```
constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      demoList: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-computed-key
        [0]: [
          {
            name: "",
            length: ""
          }
        ]
      },
      status: false
    };
  }
```

The value assigned to `demoList[0]` should be an `Array` of `object`.

It should **not** be:

```
{
    name?: string;
    length?: string;
}
```

It should be:

```
[{
    name?: string;
    length?: string;
}]
```

As well `state` update should also consider `demoList[0]` value as `Array` of `object`.

It should **not** be like:

```
this.setState({
  demoList:
  { ...this.state.demoList, [index]: { name: inputName, length: inputLength} }
});
```

It should be like:

```
handleChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      demoList: {
        0: [{ name: e.target.value, length: e.target.value.length.toString() }]
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: He's asking about flow not typescript. It's also more probable he wants to fix his types to conform to his application, not write his type and then change his whole application to suit.

Comment: There can be many angles to view a problem. I do not agree with your view, because changing `type` definition to make a code block work is not one should intend at first place.

Comment: That's why Type-safety with Type-Script is ever invented to make JavaScript applications type-safe and robust.

Answer (score -1):

Based on how you've defined your state object plus usage, I see you want to create an object with a list of keys as numbers with objects as properties. But what you've done in your `demo` type is that you defined it as an object of keys as numbers with values as an array of objects.

Below you'll see the changes I've made based on your post with the try flow [here](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgegCoa4AVATzCTgHMBXFKAEzkzQ4AZxgoYSYXBpVyMFm15IQEOAF44Ab3Jw4SlQBlgogFxaduuAG0A1kiZmAdpxAAjJFAC6ZzXCpU4AE0ITjgwIgA3YBDhABsmOAALFAi2GETjOBQpAEEoKBQmAB5fADpyuABfAD44V054YHhhRJDY-gArTlE6thRHOAhXDqQMC0tLRxQQJAB+M1EoYEd2ABpxibhYpBX0+ZEYJZX1icqTqvPRcW6zVwgIbf71yso0WOypAGFcMDgkAA8JI5eFJkOgYKVvuAII4djASmc9MoILVtLo0DDFpwMNAABThCBgYQ+SoASnME2EnFYUHxOCJpIoG3SxlKVwk6gpm30ECMpi5mz8AUksWWMAAtLxjChXNtxbDAeLRbC4I4IOLukhtsJhOKMeAGkheOK7EwNhMrAAGbwCwWq6ZIMz4fDnO1bHbsdJOl3mywvQVnX3sm4CFCxYRIDaVCi6F4WNDJFZIADKYgkuOWSn+qzgyzADQAcg6c3mGgYPelyWjLCzhGykDBU+IkLjqxMeXyYCZfWVyrW2WmkKUO8YYDmrJmATbfFMZmZSzAizMc9tdol5458zBy2vKlUo4yLHHdERgR5cVWNhjHD1J-9OZaYzWMnX2UOR6IJ2f-p5SrPIxsRAwJwUADM4sSxE+LyVEAA). Notice the area I've commented which is the only minor change I had to make.

```
import React from 'react';

/** Type guard for states */
type demo = {
  demoList: {
    [key: number]: { // You previously have this as Array<{ ... }> but it should just be an object
        name?: string,
        length?: string,
    },
  },
  status: boolean,
}

class Comp extends React.Component<{}, demo> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      demoList: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-computed-key
        [0]: {
          name: '',
          length: '',
        }
      },
      status: false
    };
  }

  changeState(index, inputName, inputLength) {
    this.setState({
      demoList:
      { ...this.state.demoList, [index]: { name: inputName, length: inputLength} }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const index = 0;
    this.state.demoList[index].name

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: If a type-guard is considered to be used, application should respect it and follow. Changing `type` to support code can be dangerous. A type can be mapped to multiple places in the application and changing `type` definition to make code work should not be acceptable.